# NodeJS, Can we use phantomJs 2 with jsreport rendering shortcut

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, jsreport

I'm trying to use jsreport to generate a pdf using node js on mac, I found this resource on jsreport site (https://jsreport.net/learn/phantom-pdf#phantomjs2), but I'm not sure how exactly to configure it with the jsreport rendering shortcut (like it's used in the code below)

```
var http = require('http');
var jsreport = require('jsreport');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  jsreport.render("<h1>Hello world</h1>").then(function(out) {
    out.stream.pipe(res);
  }).catch(function(e) {    
    res.end(e.message);
  });

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you just need to specify the full phantomjs version in request options.

```
jsreport.render({
   template: {
       content: '<h1>Hello world</h1>',
       engine: 'none', // replace this with the engine that you are using
       recipe: 'phantom-pdf',
       phantom: {
         phantomjsVersion: '2.1.1' // replace this with the exact version of phantom@2 that you have installed.
       }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for